# Is 52MB/s normal speed for formatting a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-formatting

I'm currently formatting a 12TB drive, and the speed is limited to 52MB/s. Under Windows, the same drive formats at 250MB/s.

I'm not doing a quick format (full erase) and both setups are using USB3 docks, but I accidentally powered off the one under Ubuntu and decided to test it by placing it in the Windows setup. Results are ~12-16h for a format under Windows, but 2.5 days under Ubuntu. Is it simply the different file system (ext4 vs ntfs)?

Comment: How are you formatting it? Usually people do "quick" formats which just replace the partition/filesystem metadata, but you might be doing a full format, overwriting the data with zeroes

Comment: Yes, full format. But the speed difference between Win and Ubuntu is what concerns me. Both OS are doing full format of their drives, both are connected using USB 3 docks, the only things that are different is Win is formatting in ntfs and Ubuntu in ext4

Comment: Search this site for "slow copy".  How much free memory is shown during this format?  Writes slower than "reads" (or creation) will fill up system buffers, and bring the system to a crawl.

Comment: 3.4GB of 33.5GB (10.2%) used